# Como puedo mejorar el rendimiento d ela siguiente query?... toma demasiado tiempo obtener el resultado

Tags: sql

Cuando ejecuto la siguiente consulta, los resultados toman mucho tiempo. Si ejecuto las dos consultas por separado, el resultado se devuelve inmediatamente. ¿Cómo puedo mejorarlo?

```
Select Carpeta, Estado
from SCANAPP_JOB_SIMCE with(nolock) Where Nivel = '0M' and TipoPROC = 
'CEN' and TipoQUEST = 'LTR'
and Carpeta not in
(
    Select Distinct JobName from 
    VMEFLOW01.SIMCE_2018_2MCen_Salida.dbo.PC_Base2 with(nolock)
)
```

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, necesitariamos saber los indices de las tablas, una aproximacion de los datos, el explain plan, y sobre todo de que base de datos estas hablando.. asi como esta, es imposible decirte algo...

Comment: ¿cuáles son las consultas exactas que ejecutas _por separado_? Quizás valga la pena mostrar los planes de ejecución de estas también, pero habría que incluir obligatoriamente las sentencias SQL tal como las estás ejecutando, para tratar de figurarse por qué el motor elige un plan diferente cuando haces la sub-consulta (suponiendo que realmente son equivalentes).

Comment: Prueba primero trayendo el resultado de la tabla del servidor vinculado a una tabla temporal, y usar esa tabla en el `NOT IN`. Por otro lado, por lo general tiene mejor performance usar `OPNEQUERY` para hartos datos que `SELECT col FROM linkedserver.database.dbo.table`

Comment: Las consultas extactas son las siguientes:
Select Distinct JobName from 
    VMEFLOW01.SIMCE_2018_2MCen_Salida.dbo.PC_Base2 with(nolock)

El resultado de la query anterior sirve de entrada a la segunda query, que es la siguiente:

Select Carpeta, Estado
from SCANAPP_JOB_SIMCE with(nolock) Where Nivel = '0M' and TipoPROC = 
'CEN' and TipoQUEST = 'LTR'
and Carpeta not in ....

Los en la primera tabla el indice usado es JobName, en la segunda tabla el indice usado es Carpeta

Comment: Lamak, entiendo la sugerencia de crear una tabla #temporal, pero puedes darme un ejemplo de como usar, en el contexto que estoy trabajando, el uso de OPENQUERY?

Comment: Ahí puse una respuesta con un ejemplo de `OPENQUERY`

Answer (score 3):

Por lo general, cuando debes traer varios datos desde una tabla en un servidor vinculado, obtienes mejor performance usando `OPENQUERY` en vez de `SELECT * FROM LinkedServer.DB.dbo.Table`. Esto porque la primera opción hace una única conexión al servidor vinculado, ejecuta la consulta allá, y se trae los resultados; en cambio la segunda forma hace una conexión por fila obtenida.

Trataría usando una tabla temporal o directamente `OPENQUERY`:

```
SELECT  Carpeta,
        Estado
FROM dbo.SCANAPP_JOB_SIMCE 
WHERE Nivel = '0M' 
AND TipoPROC = 'CEN'
AND TipoQUEST = 'LTR'
AND Carpeta NOT IN
(
    SELECT JobName
    FROM OPENQUERY(VMEFLOW01,'SELECT DISTINCT JobName 
                              FROM SIMCE_2018_2MCen_Salida.dbo.PC_Base2
                              WHERE JobName IS NOT NULL') x
)
;
```

O con tabla temporal:

```
SELECT JobName
INTO #Temp1
FROM OPENQUERY(VMEFLOW01,'SELECT DISTINCT JobName 
                          FROM SIMCE_2018_2MCen_Salida.dbo.PC_Base2
                          WHERE JobName IS NOT NULL') x
;

SELECT  Carpeta,
        Estado
FROM dbo.SCANAPP_JOB_SIMCE 
WHERE Nivel = '0M' 
AND TipoPROC = 'CEN'
AND TipoQUEST = 'LTR'
AND Carpeta NOT IN
(
    SELECT JobName FROM #Temp1
)
;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Lamak, utilice la segunda opcion (con tabla temporal) y el resultado casi que fue inmediato... problema resuelto!  :)

Comment: @GuillermoE.Grillo Que bueno, me alegro que haya funcionado

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

`Select Carpeta, Estado
from SCANAPP_JOB_SIMCE with(nolock)
INNER JOIN
(
    Select Carpeta as JobName
    from SCANAPP_JOB_SIMCE with(nolock) Where Nivel = '0M' and TipoPROC = 'CEN' and TipoQUEST = 'LTR'
    Except
    Select Distinct JobName from VMEFLOW01.SIMCE_2018_2MCen_Salida.dbo.PC_Base2 with(nolock)
)t
    On Carpeta = JobName`

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, porfavor explica tu respuesta, las respuestas que son sólo código son consideradas de baja calidad!

Comment: Gracias tocayo, resolvimos el problema con la sugerencia enviada por Lamak.